# Numerically listing Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, numerical

So my code is having a problem. Here's what I want to do: have one array have the original set of numbers (up to 10 numbers) and then copy and paste those numbers onto the second array. And then afterwards, the second area lists those numbers from the first array numerically (going from the lowest number to the highest).

The problem is... my second output is giving me a good output with the lowest numbers going to the highest numbers, however, at the same time, I'm getting a long list of repeated numbers and a ton of zeros if I stop my code with the `-9000` input. Can anyone tell me what the problem is and how to fix it? I don't want to sort this second array with the Array.sort() option, by the way. No importing anything but the scanner:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Input up to '10' numbers for current array: ");

    int[] array1 = new int[10];
    int i;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println("Input a number for " + (i + 1) + ": ");
        int input = scan.nextInt();
        if (input == -9000) {
            break;
        } else {
            array1[i] = input;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("\n" + "Original Array: ");

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {

        System.out.println((j + 1) + ": " + array1[j]);
    }

    System.out.println("\n" + "Organized Array: ");

    int[] array2 = new int[i];
    for (i = 0; i < array1[i]; i++) {
        System.out.println(+array1[i]);

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {

            int temp;
            boolean numerical = false;

            while (numerical == false) {
                numerical = true;

                for (i = 0; i < array1.length - 1; i++) {

                    if (array2[i] > array2[i + 1]) {
                        temp = array2[i + 1];
                        array2[i + 1] = array2[i];
                        array2[i] = temp;
                        numerical = false;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        for (i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(array2[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues that you need to fix to make your program run:

**You have forgotten to copy `array1` into `array2`**:

The output that you think is coming from sorting `array2` is actually from the process of sorting.

```
int[] array2 = new int[i];
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    array2[j] = array1[j];
}
```

**You placed the output of sorted array inside the loop that does sorting**:

Check the level of curly braces, and move the output loop to after the sorting loop

```
for (i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(array2[i]);
}
```

**Your sorting algorithm has an extra loop**:

Having the outermost loop makes no sense: your bubblesort algorithm works perfectly without it, so you should remove the loop, and move its body up by one level of nesting:

```
for (i = 0; i < array1[i]; i++) { // Remove the loop
    ... // <<== Keep the body
}
```

**Your innermost loop reuses `i` incorrectly**:

Replace loop variable `i` with another variable, e.g. `m`

```
for (int m = 0 ; m < array2.length - 1; m++) {
    if (array2[m] > array2[m + 1]) {
        temp = array2[m + 1];
        array2[m + 1] = array2[m];
        array2[m] = temp;
        numerical = false;
    }
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/CLvOIx)

Comment: Very detailed! Thank you so much for the awesome explanations!

Answer (score 0):

- in your for loop you set i limit to array1[i] value not to array lenght, surely it is wrong.
- you are reusing the same index i, inside the other loops of the outer big 'for' loop, so the i value will be messed up by inner loops
- you never copied the array1 values to array2